# Calling a scope function from an ng-include template passing template value as parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-include, angular-template

So my problem is kind of self explanatory, I want to pass a parameter which I get from the angular template engine as a parameter.

Something like:

```
<div ng-click="model.myFunc({{user.id}})">click me</div>
```

the problem is that any other numeric value passed as a parameter works fine, as emphasized by the following plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/GqTDpc?p=preview

But once I am trying to use a value from the template engine, it breaks.

**A plunker that emphasizes my exact problem:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/FdlBQ1

Comment: Dont use curly braces. Just do `ng-click="model.myFunc(user.id)"`

Comment: then it evaluates as a string and not as user.id

Comment: I dont see `user.id` anywhere in your plunk. Where does that come from?

Comment: This plunk  emphasizes the concept.

I will create another one now that will demonstrate the exact problem

Comment: Updated, doesn't work either way

Comment: CodeHater is correct. This plunk derived from yours shows that his answer works: http://plnkr.co/edit/pOW8UQ?p=preview

Comment: Yes but if you do this inside of ng-repeat you get an undefined value, which was also the original question, thanks

Comment: You mean moving the function outside the template into ng-repeat gives undefined value?

Comment: No, I mean that using user.id inside of ng-repeat, without curly braces, gives a reference with typeof undefined

Comment: Can you edit your question to link to a new plunk that shows what you are trying to do inside ng-repeat?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/FdlBQ1

Comment: I still dont understand what do you want to do inside ng-repeat?

Comment: I would like to pass the {{user.id}} as a function parameter, this way I will be able to determine which row exactly the use has clicked, or which user box I should show.
A very simple thing allegedly, but not as simple to implement as it seems

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/jXdRP6?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code changed in nested1.html

```
<div ng-init="temp=user.id"data-ng-click="layout.toggleNestedContent(temp)" style="cursor:pointer;">
{{user.name}} {{user.id}} Click me in order to display the other nested box!
</div>
```

Check below is the working example

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/o3liT3?p=preview)</kbd>